# Looking for an alternative to Holdout, that doesn't require background to be transparent

Tags: transparency, masking

I want the white bands of the cone to completely fuse with the white of the background. As it now, because fo the shadow effects, that's not the case

I was thinking about using the holdout shader for the white bands, but that only works when you set the Background to transparent. So won't have the desired effect.

I know, I could render the animation with the holdout shader and the background set to transparent, and then composite the video on a white background with my video editing software, with all the hassle and loss of quality and flexibility that entails.

Surely, there must be a solution inside Blender for this. Anyone?

I have tried completely erasing the shadows on the white bands, but unsuccessful.

Merry Xmas everybody!

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just do the compositing in Blender?

Comment: Just make your cones band emit pure white and remove the non linear color lookup in the color transforms.

Comment: @Leander setting the color to "emission" It is a serious (mental) work-around, but it does the job, if you combine it with setting 'roughness" to maximum. Thanks.